# Peewee: Outer transaction does not roll back inner transaction (savepoints)

Tags: python, transactions, peewee

Running the following python script twice throws this error:

```
peewee.ProgrammingError: relation "test_table" already exists
```

because the table does not get removed on *.rollback()*. Removing the inner transaction (*with test_db.atomic()*) works. Why does the inner transaction (which are just savepoints according to the [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/transactions.html#nesting-transactions)) not get rolled back?

```
from datetime import datetime
from peewee import Model, DateTimeField
from playhouse.postgres_ext import PostgresqlExtDatabase

"""
CREATE ROLE test WITH LOGIN;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE DATABASE test WITH OWNER test;
"""

CREDENTIALS = {
    "database": "test",
    "user": "test",
    "password": None,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "register_hstore": False,
}


test_db = PostgresqlExtDatabase(**CREDENTIALS)
test_db.connect()
test_db.set_autocommit(False)
test_db.begin()  # start transaction

class TestTable(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,))

    class Meta:
        db_table = "test_table"
        database = test_db

with test_db.atomic():

    TestTable.create_table()
    TestTable.create()

test_db.rollback()  # rollback transaction

print TestTable.get().timestamp
test_db.close()
```

**Versions**

```
peewee==2.8.3
psycopg2==2.6.2

PostgreSQL 9.5.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81), 64-bit
```

Comment: I've played around with this a bit more and even if I add a second test table **inside** the outer transaction but **outside** of _test_db.atomic()_ it does not get removed on *rollback*. Both tables get removed without the *test_db.atomic()* statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the database you're using, DDL (schema changes) may or may not be possible to rollback.

Postgresql and SQLite both appear to support rolling back DDL, but MySQL does not.

However, the Python driver for SQLite has a bug which causes it to emit a COMMIT when you issue DDL. The first patch was submitted in 2010: http://bugs.python.org/issue10740 .

Also take a look at pysqlite2, which is essentially the same as the standard-library sqlite3:

https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/ca5dc55b462a7e67072205bb1a9a0f62a7c6efc4/src/cursor.c#L537-L547

Comment: I am using Postgres (PostgresqlExtDatabase).